# Reading a dataframe from bigquery table and then delete that table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-bigquery

I am trying to read a table from bigquery and then converting it to dataframe and then finally deleting that table . But since dataframes are lazily evaluated, whats happening is it deletes the table first and then tries to read it.
Is there any way to delete the table after it has been loaded in dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are doing with dataframe, it won't execute unless you call an action. Here is what you can do: 
1. Call any action you want to perform, for e.g. you can write it as another table, let say temp_table (Remember, .write is an action)
2. Drop the table you've read from.

Comment: i know that but i don't want to perform any action (as it is not required). Is there any other way, which doesn't require to perform an action

Comment: There is no point using spark transformation unless you've a certain action to perform. Could you tell what is the purpose of this dataframe you are creating ?

Comment: so what i am doing is reading two tables(say **table1** and **table2**),  performing some transformation on both the tables, merging them together and then writing that merged table to the **table2** again , before writing i am deleting that  **table2** and then performing that write operation, so i don't require any action to be performed before deleting the table.

Comment: That is what the answer. Here action is your write method. You don't have to delete the *table2* before calling the write action. You could just say: df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).jdbc(url, "table2", connectionProps). If you are using any latest version of spark and next time you post a question, You can just update the spark version, a little bit of current code (may be pseudo ) you are trying with so that It has less chances of being a poor question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i will keep that in mind from the next time. and thanks for helping out but i think there is no driver for bigquery from google itself , there is a third party driver provided by simba (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/) but i dont want to use that since it has some limitations.